# scope and eval explanation

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, eval, scope

I have an Ajax call where I get back some JavaScript as a String. In the onSuccess Method I want to eval this code. In the JavaScript code there are Function-declarations. All these function should be accessible after the eval.

I made up a small-as-possible example. (The things are going on in the onFailure method in the example, because in JFiddle I can't make a successfull Ajax Call).

You can find the Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/ubXAV/6/

The example you see is working in all browsers (Unfortunately, this will not work in JSFiddle in IE). I marked some lines refering to questions below. Here's the code again:

```
function evalScript(script)
{
   that.eval(script); //1.
}

var that = this;

//  AJAX-Call - GadgetActionServlet
new Ajax.Request("THISWILLFAIL.com", {
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(ajaxResponse) {
            alert("success");
    },
    onFailure: function(){
        var script = "{function sayHello(){alert('Hello');}}";
        //that.eval(script); //not working in IE 2.
        evalScript(script);  //working in all browsers
    }
});
```

I read a lot in the internet about scopes and contexts in java but i just can't explain the behaviour here:

1. Why do I need to call eval on "that" ? According to many sources on the internet the context of a globally defined function is the most global context. (Here it should be window). And the code evaluated through eval should be executed in the context which is calling the eval function.
2. Assuming, that there is a new global context for the Ajax call (is it?) why can i access the evalScript function but not evaluate the script here directly.

The overall question i have is: Which particular rules apply to the usage of eval? Where are my functions attached to regarding the context? And: does an prototype Ajax call like in the example has its own global object?

Comment: You can actually make a successful AJAX call in jsFiddle, see this [reference page](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html).

Comment: I think this article will help
http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/

Comment: The word `I` is capitalised in English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off: If you can avoid using `eval`, avoid using `eval`. Does your code *have* to come back from a `POST`? Because if you're willing to use `GET` instead, you can just append a script element to the page:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = "http://example.com" +
                 "?" + encodeURIComponent("param1name") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("param1value") +
                 "&" + encodeURIComponent("param1name") + "=" + encodeURIComponent("param2value");
var parent = document.body
             || document.documentElement
             || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
parent.appendChild(script);
```

Done.

Or if it has to be `POST`, does it *really* have to be actual script code? Couldn't it be data that's *interpreted* by code already on the page? [JSON](http://json.org) is a useful data format if you can go that way.

But if it *has* to be `POST`, and what you get back *has* to be actual script code as opposed to data, then we'll have to do something like `eval`. :-)

`eval` itself is very, very special. It works within the scope in which it's used, even though it looks a bit like a function and that's not how functions work. So actually evaluating script code in global scope is hard unless the `eval` call is actually *at global scope* (not within any function call), and of course you can't do that here — you have to trigger this from your ajax callback, and so by definition this happens within a function. (**Edit**: I just thought of a way to actually use `eval` at global scope, from within a function. See the update at the end of the answer. But it's evil and horrible and wrong.)

The reason you may have seen advice saying to use `window.eval` is that a lot of modern browsers offer `window.eval` (as opposed to `eval`) which evaluates the given code in global scope. But it's not available on all browsers, and certainly not older ones.

There are workarounds, though. The IE family provides `execScript` which is *very* similar to the `window.eval` offered by other browsers, and in the worst case you can fall back on using a `script` element. Here's a global eval function that works in nearly everything:

```
window.evalInGlobalScope = (function() {
    var fname, scr;

    // Get a unique function name
    do {
        fname = "__eval_in_global_test_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    }
    while (typeof window[fname] !== 'undefined');

    // Create test script
    scr = "function " + fname + "() { }";

    // Return the first function that works:
    return test(evalInGlobalScope_execScript) ||
           test(evalInGlobalScope_windowEval) ||
           test(evalInGlobalScope_theHardWay) ||
           evalInGlobalScope_fail;

    function test(f) {
        try {
            f(scr);
            if (typeof window[fname] === 'function') {
                return f;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            try { delete window[fname]; } catch (e) { window[fname] = undefined; }
        }
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_execScript(str) {
        window.execScript(str);
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_windowEval(str) {
        window.eval(str);
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_theHardWay(str) {
        var parent, script, d = document;

        parent = d.body || d.documentElement || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (parent) {
            script = d.createElement('script');
            script.appendChild(d.createTextNode(str));
            parent.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_fail() {
        throw "evalInGlobalScope: Unable to determine how to do global eval in this environment";
    }
})();
```

..and [here's a live example of using it](http://jsbin.com/ativuc).

Note that all of the code figuring out what to use only runs once; the function that got chosen is assigned to the `evalInGlobalScope` property on `window`.

Also note that I haven't given it any return value. That's because the "hard way" version basically can't return any return value, so it's safest if none of them does. Mind you, I'm not sure what browsers still require "the hard way" — nearly everything has `execScript` and/or `window.eval` now.

---

**Update**: I said above that you couldn't use `eval` at global scope from within a function. And technically that's true, but I thought of a way to do an end-run around it. It's evil and horrible and wrong, but it does work: Use `setTimeout` instead, and give it a timeout of `0`:

```
setTimeout("your code here", 0);
```

When you give `setTimeout` a string, it performs an `eval` on it — after the timeout, *at global scope*.

Again, it's evil and horrible and wrong, and it has the added disadvantage that it's asynchronous (whereas with our `evalInGlobalScope` function, the eval happens synchronously), but it does...sort of...work. ([Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ewawib)) I **do not** recommend it.

Comment: Thank you for that great answer! That explains all my problems i stumbled upon!