# Insert and execute javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript variable:

```
var foo='<script type="text/javascript">alert("Hello World");<\/script>'
```

The variable is inserted with element.innerHTML=foo; after an event occurs on the page, about 10 seconds after the page is loaded.

Is there a way to execute the 'alert' function right after the insertion?

Comment: Yes, but it's cumbersome as you would have to `eval()` the script part. jQuery has some functions to do this out of the box - is using it an option?

Comment: The way you're inserting that tag, it's not that the code is being set up but not called, it's not being evaluated at all. (If it were, the `alert` would happen immediately.) There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do, if you give us more context.

Comment: Pekka: If your question is "Am I able to use jQuery", then yes, but if it is possible to do it in some other way, that would be better.

Comment: I am afraid this is the only way I can do it (by inserting the variable), as the "foo" is usually an object.

Comment: `innerHTML` is a hack and not very reliable across browsers.

Comment: The code is not written by me and I prefer not to make a lot of changes.

Comment: `@Ivil:` Again, if you give us more context, we can probably point you in a better direction.

Comment: @Anonymouse: `innerHTML` is in the process of being [standardized](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#innerhtml), and works better cross-browser than many other things -- just not for this (script injection). Reliability goes down dramatically if you try to create invalid DOM structures with it (setting the `innerHTML` of a `div` to "<tr><td>Hi there</td></tr>", for instance), but other than scripting, invalid structures, and some funkiness around form fields in older browsers, it's very reliable.

Comment: `innerHTML` doesn't allow for trivial appending. It's mostly used by people too lazy to care about building _proper_ DOM. I have positive experiences with proper `document.createElement('script');`, settings the appropriate attributes (which also are missing in above example) followed by `document.body.appendChild(...);`

Comment: @Anonymouse: Yes, `innerHTML` can easily be abused. In fact, *any* time I see `xyz.innerHTML += "mumble";` I wince. :-) But it's hugely useful when you're doing a whole-hog replacement provided you know what you're doing. And you don't need any attributes at all on `script` elements unless you're using something other than JavaScript, or (for inline `script` markup) if you want to use `defer` or `async` for browsers that support it.

Comment: That you don't need them doesn't mean it is more reliable to just give them anyway.
Plus, I do usually need one: `src` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you absolutely, positively have to take JavaScript code that's in a string and execute it, you basically have to use `eval` or an `eval`-like mechanism. In some years of JavaScript programming, I've never had to resort to it, and I do suggest that you look at whether there's another way to achieve your actual overall goal.

So here, you'd strip off the script tag stuff and just `eval` the code, e.g.:

```
var script = foo.replace(/^<script[^>]*>/, "").replace(/<\/script>$/, "");
eval(script);
// Or window.evalInGlobalScope(script); // -- See below
```

Obviously you have to be sure you trust the source of the string, since you're executing the code therein.

`eval` is a slippery beast and plays very odd games with context and scope. If you need something that looks more like what you'd get if you did add a script tag to the page, here's a function that does that cross-browser (from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6927621/157247) to this other question here on Stack Overflow):

```
window.evalInGlobalScope = (function() {
    var fname, scr;

    // Get a unique function name
    do {
        fname = "__eval_in_global_test_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
    }
    while (typeof window[fname] !== 'undefined');

    // Create test script
    scr = "function " + fname + "() { }";

    // Return the first function that works:
    return test(evalInGlobalScope_execScript) ||
           test(evalInGlobalScope_windowEval) ||
           test(evalInGlobalScope_theHardWay) ||
           evalInGlobalScope_fail;

    function test(f) {
        try {
            f(scr);
            if (typeof window[fname] === 'function') {
                return f;
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            try { delete window[fname]; } catch (e) { window[fname] = undefined; }
        }
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_execScript(str) {
        window.execScript(str);
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_windowEval(str) {
        window.eval(str);
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_theHardWay(str) {
        var parent, script, d = document;

        parent = d.body || d.documentElement || d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        if (parent) {
            script = d.createElement('script');
            script.appendChild(d.createTextNode(str));
            parent.appendChild(script);
        }
    }
    function evalInGlobalScope_fail() {
        throw "evalInGlobalScope: Unable to determine how to do global eval in this environment";
    }
})();
```

[Live example using the above](http://jsbin.com/ativuc)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make lots of changes, just one small change.

Right now you have such line of code:

```
oDiv.innerHTML = foo;
```

Just change it to those three lines instead:

```
var oScript = document.createElement("script");
oScript.innerHTML = foo;
oDiv.appendChild(oScript);
```

And have `foo` contain only the raw JS, without the `<script>` and `</script>` tags.

[Live text case](http://jsfiddle.net/qCVhD/).

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` on a `script` element doesn't work reliably cross-browser. It fails, for instance, in all versions of IE. Hence the various mechanisms used to find the correct `evalInGlobalScope` function in my answer.

Comment: @T.J it works with latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE. With IE9 in compatibility mode (hence IE8 as far as I know) failed indeed - know of any other browsers?

Comment: `@Shadow`: IE9, IE8, IE7, IE6 *(die! die already!)* all fail, but that's fine because they offer `execScript`. Firefox and some others offer `window.eval` (as distinct from `eval`). On just about everything else, creating a text node (rather than setting `innerHTML`) works. Again, refer to the `evalInGlobalScope` in my answer. It tests which mechanism is supported by the browser (once). I did a fair bit of research on this a couple of years ago.

Comment: OK then, was just hoping for something more simple but guess you're right as usual. :)